# How to use af:message component

Tags: jsf, message, jdeveloper

I am working on jdev 11.1.2.2.

I have an af:message component on my page displaying all the global messages.

1.But the problem is it keeps showing if its error message or an information or a warning . SO i was wondering if there is a way to hide it?

1. Is there a way to reset the message because it keeps showing the previous message even if page is refreshed ?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Using JavaScript to clear validation error messages"  in this doc http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/nov2010-otn-harvest-190744.pdf on page 14 shows how to do this.